# Where can I see what caused my pc to crash on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: crash

My pc crashed on me while I was on ubuntu (screen went black and never recovered). I am new to ubuntu so I wanted to know how I can view what caused the crash on ubuntu 16.04, maybe something similar to looking at the event viewer on windows?

Comment: The files are located in `/var/crash/` whenever something in the system crashes.

Comment: @Terrance, when I try to open it, it says I don't have permission because I am not the owner, even though I am the only account with ubuntu on this pc and have sudo privileges? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Yes, you need sudo privileges.  I might get guff for this, but you can use `sudo gedit filename`.  Graphically, you should be using `gksudo` to open files in the graphical environment.  `sudo apt install gksu`